# fill relative container with absolute content

Tags: html, css

I'm using particles.js and am trying to fill a relative section with the absolutely positioned particle content.

The problem I'm having is that the height of the relative section is dynamic and I can't seem to get the the absolutely positioned inner div to only fill the relative container.

Been searching and trying various things but haven't found any solutions. Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/awwester/3f6vkef7/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to set `position: relative;` on `.container` so `.inner` apply to body/html

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
} 
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, thanks that fixes it. I always thought divs were relative by default. Will mark correct in a few min when time allows/

Comment: No problem dude :) everyday we learn something new :), yes you need to remmeber to set position: relative; for parent to get right position: absolute; on child

Answer (score 2):

> and I can't seem to get the the absolutely positioned inner div to only fill the relative container.

The key is adding the property `position: relative` to your container.

Try the following example:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```